# ajax doesn't work on remote server

Tags: javascript, ajax, remote-server

I have this part of ajax code on my windows8

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#next_Button').click(function(){

        var text = document.getElementById("textbox");
        var query = text.value;
        $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://192.168.92.131/search2/info.php', 
            data: { query : query }
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#response').html(data);
            alert("sent query");             
        })
        .fail(function() {         
           alert( "Posting failed." );
        });

        return false;

    });
});
</script>
```

and php code on my virtual Ubuntu machine

```
echo $_POST['query'];
```

IP address is correct and it's always fixed. But ajax always says 'posting failed'. when I put html code on server and just set url :'search2/info.php'
it works. but when it's remote server with http:// ipaddress / search2 / phpname it doesn't work. By the way my php code is in var/www/html/search2 hosted on apache.
Is this problem from ajax ? even when I click on this complete url it shows server page! but ajax can't use this direct url to .php !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'm really glad to find it myself !! 
I 'v open .html by double click (it was really wrong and I never noticed) and now I understand open it on localhost or 127.0.0.1 !it works properly .
before , alert shows it works but there were no answer from server ...
And also it printed whole page!! see , I had lots of comments after the tag 
so it echo all of comments :)

Answer (score 2):

Ajax has a cross domain protection, to prevent loading from domain others than then one you browse to.

This is a security feature.
I suggest you read about it a bit here:
[jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

And there are many other questions on the subject.

Comment: other domain is preventing ajax. thanx for the tips!